# RLS: how to automatically resolve import errors in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

I recently switched from IntelliJ to Visual Studio Code, but one thing I can't figure out is how to tell my editor to automatically write a

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;
```

at the top of my file when I have something like the following import error:

[image: Rust import error in VSC]

In IntelliJ all I had to do was click on the red error icon and select "Import" and the `use` would appear at the top of the file.

I have the RLS extension for VSC. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of the RLS extension, I switched to using the [rust-analyzer](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#installation) vscode extension which supports suggesting imports as one of the "Quick Fix" options in vscode.